# Speeding up a very slow PHP script generating a large JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, google-app-engine

I currently have a web-app running on AppEngine that uses PHP to initially generate a giant JSON array, which Javascript then uses to populate elements of my web-app.

The following code **works perfectly** and does everything I want, **however takes about 10 seconds to execute**. Might not sound like a lot, but it certainly feels out of place. I'm wondering what I should be doing differently to speed up the creation of the initial array.

I've so far thought about attacking this a few ways;

- I could load **less** data initially, reducing load times as there is
  literally less to load. This would effect the general performance
  though, as right now once the data *is* loaded, each "section" is
  instant to be populated and super fast.
- I could cache some data using App Engine's
  built in Memcache. This is a neat idea however the data generated
  changes often. Often enough that a cache just wont do it.
- Use Web
  Sockets instead. I want to eventually do this, and it's on the to-do
  list, however this would mean rewriting a lot of code, so I'm not too
  fond of this right now.

I'm sure there are some "bad practise" bits and pieces within my code as well, feel free to point them out and scold me for it... [Here's the same code below as a Gist if you prefer it that way.](https://gist.github.com/Aloogy/a1ae4d86f3950a61b268a87ca5ce9371)

```
<?php
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;


# ===================================== #
# ==== Generate App Settings Array ==== #
# ===================================== #
//Existing Class (not shown) already generated $app for us...
$app_settings_array = array('app_version' => $app->app_version, 'app_server' => $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'app_id' => $app->app_id, 'app_name' => $app->app_name, 'app_logo_dark' => $app->app_logo_dark, 'app_logo_light' => $app->app_logo_light, 'app_motd' => $app->app_motd, 'app_domain' => $app->app_domain);

# ===================================== #
# ==== Generate User Details Array ==== #
# ===================================== # 
$currentuser = $_SESSION['user_id']; //Get current user id from session
$user_info = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hr_personal WHERE employee_id = :user_id LIMIT 1");
$user_info->bindParam(':user_id', $currentuser);
$user_info->execute();
$user = $user_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$email_hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $user->employee_id, '_redactedkey'); 

$log_info = $db->prepare("SELECT log_time FROM app_log WHERE log_user = :user_id ORDER BY log_time ASC LIMIT 1"); //Get 
$log_info->bindParam(':user_id', $currentuser);
$log_info->execute();
$first_seen = $log_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$user_details_array = array('id' => $user->employee_id, 'id_hash' => $email_hash, 'first_seen' => $first_seen->log_time, 'title' => $user->employee_title, 'name' => $user->employee_knownas, 'avatar' => $user->employee_avatar, 'mobile' => $user->employee_mobile, 'email' => $user->employee_email);


# ============================= #
# ==== Generate Chat Array ==== #
# ============================= #
$currentuser = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$currentapp = $app->app_id;

$chat_array = array();  

foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char) {
    $individuals = array(); 
    $countrow = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hr_personal where employee_knownas LIKE '$char%' AND employee_id IN (SELECT notification_submitter FROM notification_sent WHERE notification_id IN (SELECT notification_id FROM notification_wait WHERE user_id = '$currentuser' AND method = 'online' ORDER BY notification_id DESC))");
    $countrow->execute();
        if ($countrow->rowCount() > 0) {
        $mesage_query = "SELECT * FROM hr_personal where employee_knownas LIKE '$char%' AND employee_id IN (SELECT notification_submitter FROM notification_sent WHERE notification_id IN (SELECT notification_id FROM notification_wait WHERE user_id = '$currentuser' AND method = 'online' ORDER BY notification_id DESC))";
        $message_query_run = $db->query($mesage_query);
        while($row = $message_query_run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if(!empty($row['employee_avatar'])){
              $options = ['size' => 200, 'crop' => true];
              $image_file = "gs://rouic-cdn/internal/".$row['employee_avatar'];
              $image_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($image_file, $options);
              $image_url = preg_replace("/^http:/i", "https:", $image_url); 
            } else {
                $image_url = "";
            }

            $whileUser = $row['employee_id'];
            $message_chain = array();

            $chain_query = "SELECT * FROM notification_wait WHERE method = 'online' AND user_id = '$currentuser' AND notification_id IN (SELECT notification_id FROM notification_sent WHERE notification_submitter = '$whileUser')";
            $chain_query_run = $db->query($chain_query);
            while($chainRow = $chain_query_run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                array_push($message_chain, array('id' => $chainRow['notification_id'], 'reply_id' => $chainRow['reply_id'], 'content' => $chainRow['message'], 'time' => $chainRow['time'], 'state' => $chainRow['state']));
            }

            array_push($individuals, array('id' => $row['employee_id'], 'group' => $char, 'name' => $row['employee_knownas'], 'avatar' => $image_url, 'message_chain' => $message_chain));
        }
            array_push($chat_array, array('group' => $char, 'data' => $individuals));
    }

}   


# ========================================== #
# ==== Generate Admin Groups (if admin) ==== #
# ========================================== #
    $admin_array = array();
    if($auth->checkPage('admin', $_SESSION['user_id']) == false){ //Existing CheckPage class returns true if user is allowed on page
        array_push($admin_array, array('access' => 'denied'));
        } else {
        //Generate All Clients  
        $client_array = array();
        $client_query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_app = '$currentapp'";
        $client_query_run = $db->query($client_query);
        while($row = $client_query_run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        if(!empty($row['client_avatar'])){

          $options = ['size' => 200, 'crop' => true];
          $image_file = "gs://rouic-cdn/internal/".$row['client_avatar'];
          $image_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($image_file, $options);
          $image_url = '<span class="thumbnail-wrapper d48 circular inline m-t-5">
                                        <img id="dynamicavy" src="'.preg_replace("/^http:/i", "https:", $image_url).'" width="48" height="48">
                        </span>';   

        } else {
            $image_url = "";
        }

        $short_desc = strlen($row['client_desc']) > 30 ? substr($row['client_desc'],0,30)."..." : $row['client_desc'];
        $desc = '<span class="expandable" full-length="'.$row['client_desc'].'">'.$short_desc.'</span>';
        $actions = '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Edit Details</button>';
        array_push($client_array, array($row['client_id'], $image_url, "<b>".ucwords($row['client_name'])."</b>", $row['client_dob'], $row['client_phone'], $row['client_address'], $desc, $actions));
        }

        //Generate All Departments
            $department_array = array();
            $department_query = "SELECT * FROM departments WHERE dep_app = '$currentapp'";
            $department_query_run = $db->query($department_query);
            while($row = $department_query_run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if(!empty($row['dep_avatar'])){

              $options = ['size' => 200, 'crop' => true];
              $image_file = "gs://rouic-cdn/internal/".$row['dep_avatar'];
              $image_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($image_file, $options);
              $image_url = '<span class="thumbnail-wrapper d48 circular inline m-t-5">
                                            <img id="dynamicavy" src="'.preg_replace("/^http:/i", "https:", $image_url).'" width="48" height="48">
                            </span>';

            } else {
                $image_url = "";
            }

            $short_desc = strlen($row['dep_description']) > 30 ? substr($row['dep_description'],0,30)."..." : $row['dep_description'];
            $desc = '<span class="expandable" full-length="'.$row['dep_description'].'">'.$short_desc.'</span>';
            $actions = '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Edit Details</button>';
            array_push($department_array, array($row['dep_id'], $image_url, "<b>".ucwords($row['dep_name'])."</b>", $desc, $actions));  
            }
            array_push($admin_array, array('access' => 'granted', 'allDepartments' => $department_array, 'allClients' => $client_array));       
    }


... About 4 More sections redacted ...


# ===================== #
# ==== Final Array ==== #
# ===================== #
$init_array_compare = array('chat' => $chat_array, 'admin' => $admin_array, 'app_details' => $app_settings_array, 'user_details' => $user_details_array,  'user_permissions' => $user_permissions_array);
$hash = md5(json_encode($init_array_compare)); //I'm basically creating a hash of the results here so I can see if anything has changed if generated again 

$init_array = array('hash' => $hash, 'chat' => $chat_array, 'admin' => $admin_array, 'app_details' => $app_settings_array, 'user_details' => $user_details_array,  'user_permissions' => $user_permissions_array);


echo json_encode($init_array);
```

Comment: If I had to guess then `CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl()` is the slowest piece of your code...so basically, do that less. If that is not the slowest piece then which piece is the slowest? Or it's the fact that `SELECT * FROM hr_personal where employee_knownas LIKE '$char%' AND employee_id IN (SELECT notification_submitter FROM notification_sent WHERE notification_id IN (SELECT notification_id FROM notification_wait WHERE user_id = '$currentuser' AND method = 'online' ORDER BY notification_id DESC))` is being executed twice within a loop for some unholy reason.

Comment: Good catch on the duplicated query, honestly don't know how I didn't notice that one. I'm going to experiment with the `CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl()` part, you could be right.

Comment: I am glad to see you were able to reduce the execution time by over 90% lol. I am curious though, was it the `getImageServingUrl()` alone that had such a huge impact or did the duplicated query execution shave off a second or two as well?

Comment: It was just `getImageServingUrl()`... I always assumed Google's API's were fairly fast - but not this one.

Comment: Very nice, I am not familiar with the API but based on the name of the function it sounds like it downloads an image from the internet so I don't think it's fair to place the blame on Google but rather the TCP/IP stack in general and all of the possible network bottlenecks and dropped packets which naturally occur between your server and Google's. Even having an ultra-fast 1Gb internet connection is slower than a SATA 2 HDD connection and there is far more latency on the internet. But I digress and I'm glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: It's all to do with App Engine. The image file is already uploaded to the bucket storage, this API just generates a public link to the image. Although you're right, it does probably hang more on the TCP/IP stack as Google might have to transfer said image around their own network.

Answer (score 1):

MonkeyZeus was completely correct, it turned out to be `CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl()` causing the hanging. After writing a script to cache the URL's it generated the script now runs in under a second.